# DataGridViewComboBox Column with multiple Rows

Tags: vb.net

I have a `DataGridview` with the datasource set to a datatable filled from database tables. In the `DataGridView`, I have a `ComboBox` column that is populated from a table in the database. I have an event handler which fires on `.SelectedIndexChange` of the `ComboBox`.

I am having 2 problems:

1. When the `ComboBox`is changed the event fires as intended; however, the selected value does not display in the `ComboBox`. If the value is changed, it does not fire again. I require the selected index to change every time the value is changed.
2. After changing one combobox and the event is fired, none of the other rows seem to fire the event handler. I amguessing it is fairly simple and I am missing something quite easy but any help will be appreciated.

Form with DGV code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class ComponentQForm

    Private Sub ComponentQForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillDataTableComponentForm()

        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True

        Dim columnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()
        columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
        columnHeaderStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableComponentForm
        CreateCboColumn()
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbosupplier)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

        If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
            Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
            If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then
                RemoveHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
                AddHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        combo.SelectedIndex = combo.SelectedIndex
        Dim comboVal As Integer = combo.SelectedIndex + 1
        Dim strSQl3 As String = "SELECT tblSuppliers.Company "
        strSQl3 = strSQl3 & "FROM tblSuppliers "
        strSQl3 = strSQl3 & "WHERE tblSuppliers.Id = "
        strSQl3 = strSQl3 & comboVal
        Dim sel1 As New SqlCommand(strSQl3, MyCn)
        Dim comboValue As String
        comboValue = sel1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

        Dim itemNumber As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

        GetCostETA(comboValueP:=comboValue, itemNumberP:=itemNumber)
        AddCost()
        AddETA()
        AddTotal()
        Populating()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Module with procedures:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module ComponentQuoteProcedure
    Public DataTableComponentForm As New DataTable
    Public DataTableComponentForm2 As New DataTable
    Public DataAdpCompForm As New SqlDataAdapter
    Public comboValue As String
    Public cbosupplier As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()

    Public Sub FillDataTableComponentForm()
        OpenDBCon()
        OpenConSuppliers()

        Dim strSQl As String

        strSQl = "SELECT tbl200AV.ItemNumber, " & _
                    "tblComponents.PartNumber, " & _
                    "tbl200AV.Quantity " & _
                "FROM tbl200AV, tblComponents " & _
            "WHERE tbl200AV.ItemNumber = tblComponents.ItemNumber"



        Dim sel As New SqlCommand(strSQl, MyCn)
        DataAdpCompForm.SelectCommand = sel
        DataAdpCompForm.Fill(DataTableComponentForm)
        DataAdpCompForm.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateCboColumn()
        Dim itemscount As Integer = MyDataTblSuppliers.Rows.Count - 1
        cbosupplier.HeaderText = "Supplier"
        cbosupplier.Name = "Supplier"
        cbosupplier.MaxDropDownItems = itemscount
        cbosupplier.DataSource = MyDataTblSuppliers
        cbosupplier.DisplayMember = "Company"
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetCostETA(ByVal comboValueP As String, ByVal itemNumberP As Integer)
        Dim strSQl2 As String = "SELECT tblCompSup.ItemNumber, "
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "tblCompSup.CostPrice, "
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "tblCompSup.ETA "
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "FROM tblCompSup, tbl200AV "
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "WHERE '"
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & itemNumberP
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "' = tblCompSup.ItemNumber "
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "AND tblCompSup.Supplier LIKE '"
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & comboValueP
        strSQl2 = strSQl2 & "'"

        Dim sel As New SqlCommand(strSQl2, MyCn)

        DataAdpCompForm.SelectCommand = sel
        DataAdpCompForm.Fill(DataTableComponentForm2)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddCost()
        If Not DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Contains("CostPrice") Then
            DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Add("CostPrice")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddETA()
        If Not DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Contains("ETA") Then
            DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Add("ETA")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddTotal()
        If Not DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Contains("TotalPrice") Then
            DataTableComponentForm.Columns.Add("TotalPrice")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Populating()
        Dim newRow() As Data.DataRow
        Dim itemNumber As Integer = DataTableComponentForm2.Rows(0).Item("ItemNumber")
        newRow = DataTableComponentForm.Select("ItemNumber = '" & itemNumber & "'")
        Dim cost As Decimal = DataTableComponentForm2.Rows(0).Item("CostPrice")
        Dim eta As Integer = DataTableComponentForm2.Rows(0).Item("ETA")
        Dim quant As Integer = DataTableComponentForm.Rows(0).Item("Quantity")
        Dim total As Decimal = quant * cost
        newRow(0)("CostPrice") = cost
        newRow(0)("ETA") = eta
        newRow(0)("TotalPrice") = total
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Scale down the amount of code you are posting by attempting yourself to better pinpoint the location of the problem. To do this, use the debugger.

Comment: I have found what is causing the problem but fail to find a solution. The problem is that when the first selectedindexchange is fired everything works fine but when it is fired for a second time when a combobox is changed the itemNumber variable returns empty. Why is it only after the first time this begins to happen?

Comment: It may be because your ComboBox is local and not class level. I'm on my phone, now. I'll take a deeper look on a computer, later

Comment: Thank you so much, really do appreciate it. I will try to make that change when I get home. I really hope that solves the issue as I am truly stumped.

Comment: I have made the combo variable a class level variable of ComboBox but I am still receiving the same problem. I also changed the code abit tto the following:

Comment: Dim rowNumber As Integer= DataGridView1.SelectedCell.RowIndex      msgbox("Row number is " & rowNUmber")                             Dim itemNumber as String = DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).Value

Comment: The row number returns the correct value even on subsequent fires of the selectedindexchanged. So the itemNumber variable is being pointed to the right cell, but for some reason it brings back an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things that could be the cause of the problem. *Unfortunately, I not expert enough to be able to identify the issue*. That said, here are some things that raise my suspicion:

1. Your placement of `combo` and the object's scope. In the original post, the code shows that the `combo` object is declared and instantiated at the local level, e.g. within a method body. That means that once the method body is left, `combo` no longer exists.
2. You are trying to handle the events of a local scope object (`combo`) outside of the object's scope. Further, the event handler doesn't specify to which object the event handler is listening, e.g. `Handles combo.[Event]`
3. You have some naming collisions that might also be causing some further issues:

From original post:

```
Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
combo.SelectedIndex = combo.SelectedIndex ' Which combo is receiving 
                                          ' which combo's SelectedIndex?
```